# Linq to make sure that no two objects have same property value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I've a class called Alarm with a property called Description.

```
public class Alarm
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In a list of Alarms, I've to make sure that no two Alarm in the list have same Description.

I want to use linq to do this check and **get a list of alarms with duplicate description**.

Comment: Do you want to check it when new item is inserting?

Comment: No. I want to check on list of alarms.

Comment: Below all three answers you comment that you want a list of duplicates, but I don't see that in the question. Slightly confusing ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Bent. I've made corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dups = Alarms
  .GroupBy(a=>a.Description)
  .Where(a=>a.Count()>1)
  .SelectMany(a=>a);
```

or

```
if (Alarms
  .GroupBy(a=>a.Description)
  .Where(a=>a.Count()>1)
  .Any())
{
  throw new Exception("You got dups!");
}
```

Comment: Great answer. List of duplicates is what I wanted. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 3):

`var distinctAlarms = alarms.GroupBy(a => a.Description).Select(i => i.First()) .ToList();`

That should do it

Comment: something's missing here. this just returns distinct alarms. not if there are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Grant. But I wanted a query to find duplicates not distinct alarms.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care to find which alarms are duplicated, you can also do this:

```
if (list.Select(alarm => alarm.Description).Distinct().Count() != list.Count)
{
    // Has duplicate
}
```

Comment: Nice logic IIian. But I want a list of duplicate items.

Comment: Yep. Just putting it here as an alternative because @Robert McKee answered first. :)